# Does it make sense to apply the quality of "Identicality" to one or multiple objects?

Tags: etymology, synonyms

I'm writing a script which involves the comparison of two objects. I keep finding myself referring to this sort of test as an "identicality" check. From my preliminary research, "identicality" does not seem to qualify as a word. Also, the more I think about it, the less sense it makes to me. A single object should not be able to posses the quality of "identicality", since it requires that a second object exists for comparison, yet makes no reference to said object.

Does it make any sense to refer to the "identicality" of two objects? Should it instead be "identicalness", if that makes any more sense?

I'm not sure if "identicality", or even "identicalness" is etymologically sound either, or if it is just my mind kludging things together.

Comment: As long as it does it in a transparent and easy-to-understand manner that doesn’t go straight against established idiom, there’s nothing whatsoever wrong with your mind kludging things together. Both _identicality_ and _identicalness_ are instantly understandable words, whether dictionaries include them or not (and it’s not like either is common, so you’re not going against any established idiom), and they both sound perfectly logical to me as a quality to describe two objects being compared.

Comment: Also, why not "sameness" ?

Comment: "Does it make sense to apply the quality of “Identicality” to one or multiple objects?". No, not formally.  What you may want to do is back out a bit, create a *set* of two objects, and attach the attribute to the set. This doesn't need to be terribly explicit, because, as @JanusBahsJacquet, says, it is a readily understandable idea. But as an attribute, identicalness makes better sense applied to a set containing identical elements, rather than the elements themselves.

Comment: You open with 'I'm writing a script which involves the comparison of two objects.' Is it correct to assume that the script is a computer language like Python or JavaScript? And is it correct to assume that the objects that you are comparing are computer objects in a VM? (And I'm wondering why your three-year-old question is getting a flurry of activity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to refer to the "identity" of two or more objects.

Of course, outside maths, this sense is usually obscured by the 'distinguishing character or personality of an individual :  individuality' [Merriam-Webster] sense.

I had to search quite a way on the internet for:

> A human gene that shows identity with the gene encoding the
>   angiotensin receptor is located on chromosome 11 ...

As Peter Shor points out, choosing the lesser of two evils makes sense (if one can sort out which it is).  [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/identicality) lists

> identicality N  = identicalness.
>
> Origin Late 19th century.

It makes more sense to use this unambiguous word (it *must* refer to multiple objects) until it becomes more common than the 6th-most-common sense of 'identity' Webster's lists. And to 
continue to do so.

Comment: I hadn't thought of identity as a quality of something with respect to something else. To me, it seems like an "identity test" would determine whether or not two objects are one and the same, like someone being pointed out in a police lineup based on a composite picture. It seems more natural to me to think of "identicality" as a quality which exists between two distinct objects that happen to be copies of each other. I'm not sure if I'm just splitting hairs here, though.

Comment: RHK Webster's: **identity**: 6. exact likeness in nature or qualities: an identity of interests.

Comment: You had to search fairly hard for this, so it's clearly not a common use of the word *identity*.  It's not even clear to me that this use of the word *identity* is more common than *identicality* or *identicalness*, both of which have been used occasionally. So why not coin a new word rather than using an old word that doesn't (usually) mean what you want it to?

Comment: I suspect that the OP is using the identity concept in a computer science context. The word *identity* is consistently used in Object-Oriented languages such as Java (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1692882/509840) and Python (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748036/is-there-a-builtin-identity-function-in-python).

Comment: @rajah9 If a CS-specific usage is required, CS is the correct SE site to be asking the question on.

Comment: The OP said, "I'm writing a script which involves the comparison of two objects." This sounds like CS to me. I upvoted your answer because you unearthed an example from biology that agrees with "identity." And I'm trying to veer away from the thought of @PeterShor to coin a new word, when an old one is established in several domains.

Comment: Another domain that uses "identity" is mathematics. In the branch of linear algebra, the *identity matrix* is a matrix I that you can multiply by any matrix A, such that A*I = A. In the branch of modern algebra, an *Identity function* is such that f(x) = x. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function. My TL;DR is that *identity* is the preferred term in any context, whether Biology, CS, or Mathematics.

Comment: @rajah9 Having taught maths, I mentioned that usage in passing. 'Object' also has an even broader sense, of course. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/object) << 2a: A focus of attention, feeling, thought, or action >> In maths, it could refer to a plane shape (no substance). But these are too peripheral for ELU questions.

Comment: @Peter Shor For plane shapes, it's _congruence_.

Comment: Generally, *identity* isn't used in mathematics for two objects that are exactly the same. You generally say these objects are *equal* or *isomorphic*. The *identity* function maps every object to itself, so it's even stronger than two objects that are exactly alike.

Comment: I had in mind 'identity' as in the usage (x squared minus 1) ≡ (x + 1) (x - 1). The LHS and RHS are not just 'equal'.

Comment: When you hadn't thought of identity as a quality of something with respect to something else, how had you thought of it? What didn't work in identity as a quality with respect to something else?

Comment: Isn't 'Of course, outside maths, this sense is usually obscured by the 'distinguishing character or personality of an individual : individuality' [Merriam-Webster] sense.' clear?

Answer (score 1):

**Identicalness** *is* a word and I think it's the right word for your situation.

**Identity** could be used too, but is liable to be confusing due to its more common meaning of "being the same thing" as opposed to "being alike in every way".